# How to wait for imperative apex call from a LWC to finish running before executing next line?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, asynchronous, promises

I have two methods seen below, the first method is a wired call:

```
    @wired (firstMethodCall, {param1: 'test'})
    wiredResult(result){
        console.log('1');
        this.secondMethodCall();
        console.log('5');
    }

   secondMethodCall(){
       console.log('2');
       imperativeApexCall({param1: 'test'})
       .then(result => {
           console.log('3');
        });
        console.log('4');
    }
```

When the wired call runs, The console logs in the following order:

```
1
2
4
5
3
```

I want it to run sequentially to print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I make sure the imperative apex call has fully completed executing before the line "console.log('5')" in the wired call runs?

Comment: we cant see how you are invoking your methods, additionally, you can chain promises to execute your methods sequentially

Comment: @glls I have edited the question, the first method call is a wired call so it runs when I navigate to a page with the component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would use async/await, as in:

```
@wire (firstMethodCall, {param1: 'test'})
async wiredResult(result){
    console.log('1');
    await this.secondMethodCall();
    console.log('4');
}

async secondMethodCall(){
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>{
        console.log('2');
        var result = await imperativeApexCall({param1: 'test'});
        console.log('3');
        resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: what if imperativeApexCall does throw error from apex.

Comment: @PratapM You can use try-catch to catch any Apex error: `new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { console.log('2'); try { var result = await imperativeApexCall({ param1: 'test' }); console.log('3'); resolve(result); } catch (e) { reject(e); } });`

Comment: can we try like below  :::  @wire (firstMethodCall, {param1: 'test'})
async wiredResult(result){
    console.log('1');
try{
console.log('2');
    var result = await imperativeApexCall({param1: 'test'}); console.log('3');
}

catch(e){ console.log(e);}
    console.log('4');
}

All I did is removed secondaryMethodCall method

Comment: @PratapM Yes, but don't use `var result`, it will clash with the parameter from the wire method. Instead, use a different name, and prefer `let` or `const`, as `var` is subject to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: obviously....i did not notice...Thanks for the minor details also checking. :)